# Accessibility Inspector Warning for Dynamic Font Type

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

We implemented Dynamic Font type for our iOS native app. We customized the font sizes based on the our custom guidelines.
For example Body text style aEEELarge size is 53. But as per our custom guidelines we restricted maximum font size to 33.  We used the following code snippet which is working perfectly.

Code Snippet :

```
var customFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
customFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont, maximumPointSize: 33)
forLabel.font = customFont
```

So the problem is, Accessibility Inspector is showing the warning as below. even though we enable `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true` , still we see warning.

If we change the `maximumPointSize` as `50` the warning is going away. But as per our Guidelines maximum size is `33`. Is there any solution to suppress Accessibility Inspector warning ? Please help us if you know the solution.

[image]

Comment: Even I am also having the similar problem. Can some one suggest ?